# Transform and sum Pandas time series data using specified cols

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to transform/combine this data to show the cols starting with tf as the index and only leave the cols starting with vol as the remaining cols?

**Example starting data**:

```
                    v1  v2  v3 tf1 tf2 tf3
Timestamp                       
2011-09-01 02:36:00 1   1   0   1   1   0
2011-09-01 03:00:00 1   0   0   1   1   0
2011-09-01 03:36:00 1   0   0   1   1   0
2011-09-01 04:00:00 1   0   0   1   0   0
2011-09-01 04:33:00 1   0   0   1   0   0
2011-09-01 04:39:00 1   0   0   1   0   0
2011-09-01 05:12:00 1   0   0   1   0   0
2011-09-01 05:30:00 1   0   0   1   0   0
2011-09-01 05:36:00 1   0   0   1   1   1
2011-09-01 05:42:00 1   0   0   1   0   0
```

**Desired output**:

Desired output shows sum of values when `v1`,`v2` or `v3` are the index and `tf1`, `tf2` and `tf3` are the `dataframe` columns.

```
   tf1 tf2 tf3
v1  10  4   1
v2  1   1   0
v3  0   0   0
```

As can be seen from the above examples there were 10 times that `v1` and `tf1` were value `1`, 4 times that `v1` and `tf2` were value `1` etc.

I have attempted unsuccessfully tried to do this with `groupby` and attempted to transpose index and columns i.e. `subset[vlist].T` gives me the v1,v2 and v3 as the index but then I have the timestamp data as the cols which is not what I want.

Can this be done by a groupby with sum or similar?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result is inner product of pairs of columns. To get all of the pairs, you can do a matrix product of v-columns and tf-columns:

```
df.filter(like="v").T.dot(df.filter(like="tf"))

#  tf1  tf2 tf3
#v1 10    4   1
#v2  1    1   0
#v3  0    0   0
```

---

- `.dot` from the docs, is the *Matrix multiplication with DataFrame or Series objects*
- Since the v-columns are transposed, the `dot` product will give `(v1 * tf1).sum(), (v1 * tf2).sum(), ... (v3 * tf3).sum()` according to the definition of matrix multiplication.

Comment: OMG! stole my answer! :-)

Comment: Can you please explain what does the `.dot` element does to the data?  Does it multiply the cols and index data?  thanks

Comment: It is a matrix multiplication. Basically here, it calculates the inner product of all pairs of columns (one from v and one from tf).

Comment: it's great answer!

Comment: @MaxU Thank you! :)

Comment: Apologies, I thought I had already accepted the answer @Psidom.  Will accept now